# pyQGIS returns invalid layer with QgsVectorLayer in QGIS 3

Tags: pyqgis, layers, qgis-3, python-3, qgsvectorlayer

I have the following problem :
I've installed all pyQGIS environment on Windows 7. I work with 64 bits version of Python 3.6 and QGIS 3.0 and PyQt5. My Windows paths are ok.

My objective is to **create an empty QGS project** with stand-alone python script and **add layers** into.

But when I try to read a shapefile (the shp is good when I open it in QGIS GUI) I get an invalid `QgsVectorLayer` :

```
import os

from qgis.core import QgsApplication, QgsProject, QgsVectorLayer
from PyQt5.QtCore import QFileInfo

QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("C:\\QGIS 3.0\\apps\\qgis", True)
qgs = QgsApplication([], False)
qgs.initQgis()

pathQGS = "C:\\path\\to\\project.qgs"
layerPath = "C:\\path\\to\\layer.shp"
fileInfo = QFileInfo(layerPath)
path = fileInfo.filePath()
baseName = fileInfo.baseName()

project = QgsProject.instance()
if os.path.isfile(pathQGS):
    os.remove(pathQGS)
project.setFileName(pathQGS)
layer = QgsVectorLayer(path, baseName, 'ogr')
if not layer.isValid():
    print("Layer is not valid")
project.addMapLayer(layer)
project.write()

qgs.exitQgis()
```

How can I solve this ? I checked many other topics without finding any answer to my problem.

Can you please help me ?

Comment: I just noticed you didn't describe exactly what error (messages) you are getting from running this code. Were you able to run through all lines of codes without exception? I suspect there might be some issue with the QGIS prefix path...

Comment: Exactly. I don't get any errors but when I try for example to read columns names I get : `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'fieldNameByIndex'`

Comment: EDIT : when I change the value of `QgsApplication.setPrefixPath` it doesn't change anything in `os.environ['QGIS_PREFIX_PATH']` ... Maybe this is the link to the issue.

Comment: I think you should have called `fieldNameIndex` (not `fieldNameByIndex`). Also you should call it via layer data provider like this: `layer.dataProvider().fieldNameIndex("aFieldName")`

Comment: The `QgsApplication.setPrefixPath` won't change the `QGIS_PREFIX_PATH` environ variable value. I am curious how did you install your QGIS 3 software? because that path is a little unusual.

Comment: I installed my QGIS with the standalone executable and I wanted a minimum path so I created a folder at the root. I'll try your method but for the `project.addMapLayer(layer)` it should work if the layer was valid isn't it ?

Comment: Yes, I didn't see anything intrinsically wrong with your script and I ran it in my osgeo installed QGis environment without any problem, I did just change that project instantiation line, but now I am not so sure that's the problem.

Answer (score 1):

To create a QgsProject object, simply do the following:

```
project = QgsProject()
```

I tried the rest of your code and worked, it create a .qgs qgis project file, of course if your layer is not valid, it might make the `.addMapLayer()` call fail.

Comment: As I said, I opened my layer in QGIS and checked the valididty. The invalid output layer is empty. I think the problem has another reason.

Comment: I added a point layer into the .qgs project and it saved and can be opened in QGIS 3.0, project and the data layer without issue.